# Reverse engineer Ceasar cipher

Tags: python, reverse-engineering

I reverse engineered to decrypt, but do not get the expected result.

For example, entering

```
Lipps${svph%
```

with offset 4 should result in

```
Hello World!
```

but I get

```
ello´world³
```

What did I do wrong?

```
code = input("Enter text to decrypt: ")
distance = int(input("Enter number of offset: "))
plainText = ''
for ch in code:
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordValue - distance
    if cipherValue < ord('a'):
        cipherValue = ord('z') - \
            (distance - (ord('a') - ordValue + 1))
    plainText += chr(cipherValue)
print(plainText)
```

Comment: Why did you use `if cipherValue < ord('a')`?

Comment: Having done a ceasar decrypt/encrypt before. Have you thought about generating a map dictionary instead of trying to do ord and then shift around uppercases? That shift is part of your problem.

Comment: My knowledge on python is limited and only know what the text teaches.

Comment: As an update, I've tried reworking my current code a few times, but still have the same unexpected results.

Comment: I may be clueless here, but I thought Caesar cyphers remained within the same a-zA-Z bounds, so where are the non-alphanums coming from?  What's your upper and lower end for the covered range?

Comment: I think you seem to anchoring at `a` `z` rather `a-Z` + whatever `!` goes up to.   if you want to encode punctuation characters then your upper and lower bounds to wrap back need to be set correctly.  I suggest you take your `ord('a')` out of the body, bring them up as variables on top and get them working correctly just using a-z type d characters first.  then expand the range to A-Z & tweak to correctness.  finally expand to punctuations and whatever.

Comment: At this stage in my skills, I'm unsure how to recode for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working for a-z and gave you a little test framework to enter/check automatically rather than typing it in every time.

```
def dowork(code, distance, lower, upper):


    bounddown, boundup = ord(lower), ord(upper)

    plaintext = ""
    for ch in code:
        ordValue = ord(ch)
        cipherValue = ordValue - distance
        if cipherValue < bounddown:
            cipherValue = boundup - bounddown - ordValue +1

        plaintext += chr(cipherValue)


    return plaintext

dataexp = [
    (("jgnnq",2, 'a', 'z'),"hello"),
    ]

for input_, exp in dataexp:
    got = dowork(*input_)
    msg = "exp:%s:%s:got for %s" % (exp, got, inp)
    if exp == got:
        print("good! %s" % msg)
    else:
        print("bad ! %s" % msg)
```

This prints

```
good! exp:hello:hello:got for ('jgnnq', 2, 'a', 'z')
```

Now all you need to do is add an extra item to the dataexp list, something like

`(("Lipps${svph%", 4, <lowerbound>, <upperbound char>), "Hello World!")`

once you have the upper and lower bound figured out it should work.  Notice that I didn't know caesar code, I just copied yours directly but restructured it a bit.

what `*_input` does is to take those 4 values in that tuple (more or less a list) and assign them to `code, distance, lower, upper` in the `dowork` function.

`lower` is what corresponds to `a` in your code and `upper` is `z`.

exp is what you expect and `exp == got` just checks whether what the function returned is correct or not.  once you get the function correct it should work for **both** my simplistic `a-z`, 2 distance, `hello` test and your more complicated 4 distance but including punctuation

#### lower and upper bounds

your 2 strings, input and output, are `Lipps${svph%` and `Hello World!`.  That means all of these characters need to fall within your upper and lower ord values, right?  So the minimum ord position of all those is your `lower` and the max is your `upper`.  Now, I'm not the guy from Cryptonomicon and I can't ever remember if ord(a) < ord(A) or not, let alone the punctuations.  So you'll have to kind tinker with that, which is why I based my test on only the lower case letters. I'd add 0-9 though.

### final version

This does not need you to figure out which character to put at lowest bound and which at upper.  We take lower = 32 (start of printable chars), upper = 255.  That way punctuations, upper and lower case, digits, their ord values dont matter anymore.

```
#full ASCII range, you can go to town on entering whatever you want
bounddown, boundup = 32, 255

plaintext = ""
for ch in code:
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordValue - distance
    if cipherValue < bounddown:
        cipherValue = boundup - bounddown - ordValue +1

    plaintext += chr(cipherValue)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your code doesn't include an option to enter the text and distance, but a pre-wrote database?

Comment: put it this way.  when `dowork` is good, you can paste in your user ask code back again.  in the meantime, it keeps you from driving yourself crazy entering it manually each and every time.  *database* is a rather grandiose term, but, yes, that's what dataexp is used for.

Comment: I cut and paste the same little dumb loop to test slightly complicated functions like your caesar so that I don't need to check multiple runs manually.  **your code was already, again, correct as is**, you just need to watch your bounds tests.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to rework the output so it only shows the conversion. Trying to figure out what to edit out.

Comment: hmm, leave the output as is for now, because it shows the test results for you.  get your `lower, upper` figured out, see if `dowork` works and once that's done you can go to town and restructure.  in fact, once you have a working `dowork`, leave my code alone, copy `dowork`, hardcode the `upper` and `lower` and put back your user input code and output.  if you haven't used the wonders of source control, `git` can be useful to keep track of copies that worked and those that didnt

Comment: actually, it's really confusing to be dealing with your punctuations, where they sit and other characters that you might want to use.  you are on the ASCII character set, basically, so just `ord(0)` as lower and `ord(255)` as upper.  You got your ciphered text slightly wrong because I get `Hello world` with a lower case `w` given your input.

Comment: see my final version.  it does away with figuring what characters to check for lower and upper.

Comment: When doing program checks, it automatically inputs other cyphers. Enter the coded text: Lipps${svph%
Enter the distance value: 4 is only to check if it's working.

Comment: It also automatically tests Test for Jhss'tl'Pzothls5, 7    Zu&hk2&ux&tuz&zu&hk, 2     and Khoor#zruog$, 3

Comment: That is exactly its purpose, wil m.  Making your life easier.  Once the cypher code works, copy that bit only to wherever you need to use it.

Comment: how to correct your cipher text?  well, test with either `print(chr(ord("W") + 4))` or `print(chr(ord("W") - 4))`, not really sure which way the offset needs to go.

Comment: if either answer addressed your question consider accepting it.  also, I want to qualify my all-ASCII, all-good answer : a number of characters in that range are unprintable, or can't be meaningfully entered.  for example, tab will... tab you out.  you may have to settle for a more limited range of characters that *don't* include any problem characters.  https://flaviocopes.com/non-printable-ascii-characters/  - tab falls within it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a implementation for encrypting and decrypting when the input for characters within a certain range (in this case `a-z`). You can adapt this for other ranges depending on what you need.

```py
def caesar(text, offset, decrypt=False):
    lower_bound, upper_bound = ord('a'), ord('z')
    if decrypt:
        offset = (upper_bound - lower_bound + 1) - offset
    result = ''
    for t in text:
        o = ord(t)
        if lower_bound <= o <= upper_bound:
            new_t = o + offset
            if new_t > upper_bound:
                new_t = (new_t % upper_bound) + lower_bound - 1
            result += chr(new_t)
        else:
           result += t
    return result
```

Then you can call:

```
caesar(caesar('hello world!', 2,), 2, True)
# => 'hello world!'
```

Comment: the simplification, once I thought of it is just to use chr(0), chr(255), the full ASCII range.  the whole concept remains the same as simple caesar and your code, just dont need to worry about the *@%&~ positions ;-)

Comment: Ok, I understand and altered the program, which worked. Thank you

Comment: @wilmckenzie If you're satisfied with the answer please upvote and mark it as solved.