# splitting nested quotes and commas without regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, split

When I run my code it seems to have a bug, the code helps me split but keep comma but it should keep a quote if two are linked together. It seems to have three quotes linked together

input

```
Result = parseCSV('""')
print(Result)
```

expected output

```
['"']
```

actual output

```
['']
```

code:

```
def parseCSV(string):

    results = []
    current = ''
    is_quoted_right_now = False
    in_quotes = False


    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        currentletter = string[i]

        if currentletter == '"':
            if is_quoted_right_now == True:
                if in_quotes == True:
                    current = current + currentletter
                    in_quotes = False 
                else:
                    in_quotes = True

            else:
                is_quoted_right_now = True
                in_quotes = False

        else:

            shouldCheck  = False

            if is_quoted_right_now == True:

                if in_quotes == True:
                    is_quoted_right_now = False
                    in_quotes = False

                    shouldCheck = True

                else:
                    current = current + currentletter

            else:
                shouldCheck = True

            if shouldCheck == True:
                if currentletter == ',':
                    results.append(current)
                    current = ''

                else:
                    current = current +  currentletter

    results.append(current)
    return results
```

here's a few tests and results:

```
Result = parseCSV('","')
print(Result)
#result = [',']

Result = parseCSV('"""')
print(Result)
#result = ["]

Result = parseCSV('hi,i,am,splitting')
print(Result)
#result = ['hi','i','am','splitting']

Result = parseCSV('"hi,I,am,not,splitting"')
print(Result)
#result = ['hi,I,am,not,splitting']

Result = parseCSV('abc, """')
print(Result)
#result = ['abc', '"']

Result = parseCSV('abc, ""')
print(Result)
#result = ['abc','']
#wanted result = ['abc','"']
```

As you can see, there is just one problem, my dad says I have to use pure python with no modules so can anyone help without using things like regex

Thanks!!

I would really like for someone to post a sample code, thanks!!

Comment: some thoughts:  1) are there limits/constraints on inputs?  do they have to be well-behaved in some way?  mostly thinking about double quotes.  2) are single quotes allowed *within* the strings?  3) what would `'"hi,I,am,not,splitting'` result in?  `['"h',...]`? 4) are you using unit tests?  the risk with manual tests with this type of problem is that, as you solve 1 case, say your last one, you break others.  that risk will always exist, but you want to know about it right away - and that means automated tests.  there are libraries to do that, can you use them?

Comment: if not, here's an answer I gave someone to unrelated question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60795948.  look at the end of first block of code however, at the `dataexp` section.  you could easily load your *inputs*, along with your *wanteds*.  5) *state machines* are one way to approach the kind of what-is-my-currrent-situation problem you are dealing with 6) going back to `hi i am not splitting` if are expected to handle a missing `"` at the extreme right - my #3 question, the answer can only be known once the whole string is scanned and then you have to backtrack and handle all `,` differently.

Comment: so maybe another way is to scan the whole string, note positions of the `,`, `"` and everything else and then somehow classify the state of the whole string.  not saying that **is** the way, but i would think about it.  7) the reason you aren't getting too many answers is that it is a non-trivial problem which requires a fair bit of work cover all cases.  13 and a beginner?  congrats on how far you're getting many would struggle to get that far.  8) title ?.  `splitting nested quotes and commas without regular expressions`?  9) good luck. 10) use `git` or similar to assist you.

Comment: @JL Peyret it helped a lot, thanks